# Is there a way to reverse engineer the commands to create a database schema?

Tags: mysql

I have an existing MySQL database with many tables, and I want to turn the schema into SQL statements that could be used to replicate database (or at the very least, all of the `CREATE TABLE` statements).

In MySQL Workbench I can right-click on any individual table and copy the CREATE statement for it, but I don't see a way to do this for the entire database.

Answer (score 1):

Export your database in phpMyAdmin make sure to check structure only. Or you can the command line:

```
mysqldump --no-data -u someuser -p mydatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can reverse engineer you DB using MySQL Workbench.
   It is under Database in menu: Database | Reverse Engineer & Provide connection information.
2. As already mentioned, you can create script using [mysqldup CLI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). 
   If you have triggers, storage procedures, events -- do not forget to include special params:

```
mysqldump --no-data --host=server --user=usr --password=pwd --events --routines --triggers db-name
```

3. Finally, 3rd party tools can be used to dump DB (with or without data) into sql-file or directly into different DB server.
   I'm personally using free [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) GUI on Windows.